# Repetition Probability of Matching items

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

There are 64 pieces of paper laid out from 1 to 64. 64 other pieces of paper identically marked are randomly picked from a bin and assigned to the original 64 pieces of paper at random (does not have to be assigned to the same number but each original number can only accept one number). Without replacing a picked piece of paper and picking pieces of paper from the bin till none are left, what is the probability of both papers marked 1 being put together?

Comment: isn't it just $\frac{1}{64}$?

Comment: Well, it is 1/64^2 on the first stage since there is a 1/64 of choosing paper 1 AND a 1/64 of choosing paper 1 from the laid out pile. That's about all I have figured out though.

Comment: But you start at the laid out pile at 1? Because then it's just one trial and it's only $\frac{1}{64}$ for that one trial. By the way: besides the thing you have figured out: is there another question then? Or  is it just to check?

Comment: I know its really confusing because I'm bad at explaining but the first pile has 64 papers and there are 64 more papers randomly chosen then, once that paper is chosen it's randomly distributed to the laid out pile.

Comment: If it helps maybe think of it like a tennis tournament with 128 people with 64 nationalities (2 people per nation) and one of each nationality (64 people) are already put onto one court each (64 courts in total). What are the chances of an American getting matched with an American?

Comment: Your way, there is a $\frac1{64^2}$ probability the first slot has both $1$s, a $\frac1{64^2}$ probability the second slot has both $1$s, and so on, with each success being mutually exclusive of the others so you can add the probabilities, making the answer $64 \times \frac1{64^2} =\frac1{64}$.  That is the same as @Steven31415's quick and direct answer, which also has the merit of working when the initial layout is not random

Comment: But what if the 1 is chosen last or not first, or if another number gets matched with the 1 before the 1 is even selected. Sorry I just don't really understand how it could be 1/64, not trying to be difficult.

Comment: waittt i get it